# Calculate Sum in matrix of SSRS report by column value

Tags: matrix, reporting-services

The report is designed to display the hours actually worked and the hours an employee should have worked between two specified dates. For this I used a matrix.

The problem is in total row. The actually worked hours are counted correctly, and the hours that the employee should have worked are counted not by the sum of the column, but as a Cartesian product.
Can I sum "Base Work Hours" by the column value?
[image]

On the picture above the total "Base Work Hours" should be 400.

My report:
[image]

WorkHours calculated as

```
select
    (DATEDIFF(DAY, @dtStartDate, @dtEndDate) + 1
    - DATEDIFF(WEEK, @dtStartDate, @dtEndDate) * 2
    - CASE  WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @dtStartDate) in (1, 7) THEN 1 ELSE 0    END
    - CASE  WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @dtEndDate) in (1, 7) THEN 1 ELSE 0    END
    ) 
    * WorkHoursDay
    FROM    tblEmpl
```

Comment: its a logical error - 40*28 = 1120. and ur resultset is returning 28 rows. You shud use a different criteria for Total Workhours as it is a constant.

Comment: Thank you, @ViralJain, but what you mean by "different criteria"?

Comment: How is the `WorkHours` data returned in your dataset query? Can you edit your question and give a sample of a couple of rows of data.

Comment: @Yulia: Sorry, I saw ur query just now after almost 70 days - I hope it's resolved already. 
You may consider TOTALBASEHOURS = 40 (Base Hour per Employee)* 10 (No. of employees) = 400 (Total Base Hours)